# jq - How to extract domains and remove duplicates

Tags: json, jq

Given the following json:

Full file here: https://pastebin.com/Hzt9bq2a

```
{
    "name": "Visma Public",
    "domains": [
      "accountsettings.connect.identity.stagaws.visma.com",
      "admin.stage.vismaonline.com",
      "api.home.stag.visma.com",
      "api.workbox.dk",
      "app.workbox.dk",
      "app.workbox.co.uk",
      "authz.workbox.dk",
      "connect.identity.stagaws.visma.com",
      "eaccounting.stage.vismaonline.com",
      "eaccountingprinting.stage.vismaonline.com",
      "http://myservices-api.stage.vismaonline.com/",
      "identity.stage.vismaonline.com",
      "myservices.stage.vismaonline.com"
    ]
}
```

How can I transform the data to the below. Which is, to identify the domains in the format of `site.SLD.TLD` present and then remove the duplication of them. (Not including the subdomains, protocols or paths as illustrated below.)

```
{
    "name": "Visma Public",
    "domains": [
      "workbox.co.uk",
      "workbox.dk",
      "visma.com",
      "vismaonline.com"
    ]
}
```

I would like to do so in jq as that is what I've used to wrangled the data into this format so far, but at this stage any solution that I can run on Debian (I'm using bash) without any extraneous tooling ideally would be fine.

I'm aware that regex can be used within jq so I assume the best way is to regex out the domain and then pipe to unique however I'm unable to get anything working so far I'm currently trying this version which seems to me to need only the text transformation stage adding in somehow either during the jq process or with a run over with something like awk after the event perhaps:

```
jq '[.[] | {name: .name, domain: [.domains[]] | unique}]' testfile.json
```

This appears to be useful: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/537

One solution was offered which does a regex match to extract the last two strings separated by . and call the unique function on that & works up to a point but doesn't cover `site.SLD.TLD` that has 2 parts. Like `google.co.uk`  would return only `co.uk` with this jq for example:

```
jq '.domains |= (map(capture("(?<x>[[:alpha:]]+).(?<z>[[:alpha:]]+)(.?)$") | join(".")) | unique)'
```

Comment: Does this work - https://jqplay.org/s/AJAft-xVvi

Comment: Sorry, no. But thanks. As it has the subdomains in. I'm looking for `DOMAIN.TLD`. e.g. `example.co.uk`. Also it has some paths in like `example.co.uk/page`. And I'm aiming for a final format like: ```{
    "name": "Visma Public",
    "domains": [
      "workbox.dk",
      "visma.com",
      "vismaonline.com"
    ]
}```

Comment: Good luck trying to do this in `jq`

Comment: @Inian Like I said in the question - if there's an easier way using something else I'm happy to go that route. I may try in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A programming language is much more expressive than jq.

Try the following snippet with `python3`.

```py
import json
import pprint
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

def get_tlds():
    f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat")
    content = f.read()
    lines = content.decode('utf-8').split("\n")
    # remove comments
    tlds = [line for line in lines if not line.startswith("//") and not line == ""]
    return tlds

def extract_domain(url, tlds):
    # get domain
    url = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "")
    url = url.split("/")[0]
    # get tld/sld
    parts = url.split(".")
    suffix1 = parts[-1]
    sld1 = parts[-2]
    if len(parts) > 2:
        suffix2 = ".".join(parts[-2:])
        sld2 = parts[-3]
    else:
        suffix2 = suffix1
        sld2 = sld1
    # try the longger first
    if suffix2 in tlds:
        tld = suffix2
        sld = sld2
    else:
        tld = suffix1
        sld = sld1
    return sld + "." + tld

def clean(site, tlds):
    site["domains"] = list(set([extract_domain(url, tlds) for url in site["domains"]]))
    return site

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "Hzt9bq2a.json"

    cache_path = "tlds.json"
    if os.path.exists(cache_path):
        with open(cache_path, "r") as f:
            tlds = json.load(f)
    else:
        tlds = get_tlds()
        with open(cache_path, "w") as f:
            json.dump(tlds, f)
    
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        d = [clean(site, tlds) for site in d]
        pprint.pprint(d)
        with open("clean.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(d, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

May I offer you achieving the same query with `jtc`: the same could be achieved in other languages (and of course in **jq**) - the query is mostly how to come up with the **regex** to satisfy your ask:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<domains>l:>((?:[a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)[^.]*$<R:' -u'{{$1}}' /\
                      -ppw'<domains>l:><q:' -w'[domains]:<[]>j:' -w'<name>l:'
{
   "domains": [
      "stagaws.visma.com",
      "stage.vismaonline.com",
      "stag.visma.com",
      "api.workbox.dk",
      "app.workbox.dk",
      "workbox.co.uk",
      "authz.workbox.dk"
   ],
   "name": "Visma Public"
}
bash $
```

Note: it does extract only `DOMAIN.TLD`, as per your ask. If you like to extract `DOMAIN.SLD.TLD`, then the task becomes a bit less trivial.

### Update:

Modified solution as per the comment: extract `domain.sld.tld` where 3 or more levels and `domain.tld` where there’s only 2

PS. I'm the creator of the `jtc` - JSON processing utility. This disclaimer is SO requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I do need `site.SLD.TLD` for all of them. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: if you could come up with criteria how to distinguish SLD, then it could be programmed, but unfortunately it's a question of semantics, thus, as pointed by @hobbs, it then requires parsing the suffix list (so that the solution is comprehensive)

Comment: I think the jq project found a way: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/537 However I'm unable to understand how to implement it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What you can do easily though - extract `domain.sld.tld` for all of those which have 3 and more levels, and `domain.tld` for those which have only 2 levels

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions presented on this page offers that:

> A programming language is much more expressive than jq.

It may therefore be worthwhile pointing out that jq is an expressive, Turing-complete programming language, and that it would be as straightforward (and as tedious) to capture all the intricacies of the "Public Suffix List" using jq as any other programming language that does not already provide support for this list.

It may be useful to illustrate an approach to the problem that passes the (revised) test presented in the Q.  This approach could easily be extended in any one of a number of ways:

```
def extract:
  sub("^[^:]*://";"")
  | sub("/.*$";"")
  | split(".")
  | (if (.[-1]|length) == 2 and (.[-2]|length) <= 3
     then -3 else -2 end) as $ix
  | .[$ix : ]
  | join(".") ;
```

```
{name, domain: (.domains | map(extract) | unique)}
```

#### Output

```
{
  "name": "Visma Public",
  "domain": [
    "visma.com",
    "vismaonline.com",
    "workbox.co.uk",
    "workbox.dk"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your example, you don't actually want top-level domains (just one component, e.g. ".com"), and you probably don't *really* want second-level domains (last two components) either, because some domain registries don't operate at the TLD level. Given `www.foo.com.br`, you presumably want to find out about `foo.com.br`, not `com.br`.

To do that, you need to consult the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/). The file format isn't *too* complicated, but it has support for wildcards and exceptions. I dare say that jq isn't the ideal language to use here — pick one that has a URL-parsing module (for extracting hostnames) and an existing Public Suffix List module (for extracting the domain parts from those hostnames).